# How to run commands from a c# asp.net core web api on a java cli application that is running in a Linux virtual machine?

Tags: java, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building a REST API Wrapper for Whitesource CLI. the setup is that the whitesource cli is installed in a linux virtual machine and the ASP.Net core Web API should be able to call the whitesource cli running in the linux vm and be able to run commands there. How can i do this?

I am looking for ways to do that. this diagram is just a basic that explains what i am trying to do! thanks.

[image: How to call Java Commandline application running in a virtual machine from C# Asp.net Core Web API?]

Comment: Is the VM on the same box?

Comment: can you run a lightweight server on the linux VM that has a REST endpoint that run the command lines with exec()?